# how to do math in angular expression?

Tags: angular

I am trying to do math on angular expression. The values are from a json file.

Example:

```
data.one = 1

data.two = 2
```

I tried `{{(data.one)*(data.two)}}` but didn't work. Please advise.

And is there any difference between `angularjs` and `angular` (2 / 4 ) for the math function?

Comment: `{{ data.one * data.two }}`

Comment: thanks. i tried {{data.one*data.two}} before.. it needs space

Comment: Space is not necessary

Comment: Math operations are easily done in angular. All you need to do is just check the website thoroughly. It's not that hard to find the answer over there. Here is the link from [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

it's bad practice to do any calculation in template, instead do Your calculations in `...component.ts` file:

`data.sum = (data.one * data.two);`

and in template use the result:

`{{ data.sum }}`